# Using gridview with Datasource, can't get new values but need to use databind otherwise the grid view is empty in code behind

Tags: gridview, datasource

I am using datasource with Gridview which means that when the Update button is clicked, it fires the rowupdating but the gridview is empty.  In order to fill the Gridview I need to do a databind.  but when I do the databind the newvalue is lost.

Help, help, help.

Here is the Gridview markup:

```
<asp:GridView ID="Segmentsgvw" runat="server"
    AllowPaging="True"
    AllowSorting="True"
    AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    CellPadding="4"
    EnableViewState="False"
    EmptyDataText="No Segments currently defined"
    ForeColor="#333333"
    GridLines="None"
    DataKeyNames="pk_segmentId"
    PageSize="4"
    Width="100%"
    autogenerateeditbutton="false"
    autogenerateupdatebutton="true"
    OnRowUpdating="Segmentsgvw_RowUpdating"
    OnRowUpdated="Segmentsgvw_RowUpdated"
    OnRowEditing="Segmentsgvw_RowEditing"
    OnRowDataBound="Segmentsgvw_RowDataBound"
    onrowcancelingedit="Segmentsgvw_RowCancelingedit"
    OnRowDeleting="Segmentsgvw_RowDeleting"
    onpageindexchanging="Segmentsgvw_PageIndexChanging"
    onDataBound="Segmentsgvw_DataBound"    
      >

    <Columns>
        <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" ShowDeleteButton="True" ShowHeader="False" causesvalidation="false" />
               <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Segment Name" 
             HeaderStyle-Width="14%"
            SortExpression="segmentname">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="gvsegmentnametbx" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("segmentname") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="gvsegmentnamelbl" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("segmentname") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
```

Here is the rowupdating code:

```
    protected void Segmentsgvw_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
        string fillquery = "SELECT * FROM Segments WHERE fk_modelmaster = @fk_modelmaster";
        FillGridviewDataNoDatabind(fillquery, Segmentsgvw, Convert.ToInt32(ModelSelectddl.SelectedValue));
        GridViewRow updatingRow = Segmentsgvw.Rows[e.RowIndex];
        int RowIndex = e.RowIndex;

        int rowCount = Segmentsgvw.Rows.Count;
        Globalvar.glAllowEditFlag = true;
        TextBox tmp_gvsegmentnametbx = (TextBox)updatingRow.FindControl("gvsegmentnametbx");
     // the textbox is null unless the FillGridViewData is databound.
```

Here is the FillGridviewDataNoDatabind:

```
   public void FillGridviewDataNoDatabind(string query, GridView ActiveGridView, int filter)
    {
        // Use this
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Globalvar.gl_SQLConnstring);
        try
        {
            if (conn.State != ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                conn.Close();
                conn.Open();
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            Globalvar.gl_ErrorCode = "1017";
            Response.Redirect("Errorpage.aspx");
            return;
        }
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter(query, conn);
        ad.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fk_modelmaster", filter);
        ad.Fill(ds);

        if (ds != null)
        {
            if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count != 0)
            {

                ActiveGridView.DataSource = ds;
           //     ActiveGridView.DataBind();


            }
            else
            {
                ActiveGridView.DataSource = null;
            //    ActiveGridView.DataBind();

            }
        }
```

Comment: So I need to get the new value in the rowupdating in order to do various validation checks.  I have removed every instance of 'causes validation' elsewhere.

Comment: No problem anymore.  I decided to code this very differently.  The problem still exists however.